# HQL with fully qualified class name

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, jpa-2.0

Let's say I have entity Foo like -

```
package com.some.company.model;
// imports
@Entity
public class Foo{
    @Id
    private Long id;    

    // getters / setters and other properties omitted   
}
```

so while dealing with Entity through HQL I prefer to refer the Entity by fully qualified class name like -

```
entityManager.createQuery(String.format("delete from %s where id = :id", Foo.class.getName()))
                .setParameter("id", fooId)
                .executeUpdate();
```

I noticed one thing in `@Entity` annotation - the name property has a unqualified name of the entity class by default. which makes me think why unqualified name? 
Which should I use in HQL unqualified name or fully qualified name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point to use the fully qualified name because Hibernate won't allow duplicate entity names. So if you had different entities with the same name, in different packages. Hibernate will throw a DuplicateMappingException.

Comment: hmm.. seems like hibernate internally deals with unqualified class names, right?

Comment: It probably has a Map with entityName as the key.

Comment: That means If I specify fully qualified class name, hibernate needs to do extra work?

Comment: well Like I said I'm not sure how it works. just assuming it uses a map, which is why the entitynames can't be duplicates. But it is extra work for you. Why do you want to do the full Package+class?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes a difference, but... I prefer unqualified name simply because it is shorter and it makes my HQL easier to comprehend. The only reason I can think of to use fully qualified name is you have 2 different `Foo` entities (say, from different packages), in this case, I would much rather map them into different entity names (say, `AFoo`, `BFoo`) rather using fully qualified names to differentiate them.

Comment: Hibernate won't allow duplicate entity names.

Answer (score 0):

For non-entity class, you have to provide also package (getName())
HQL query cannot solve if you have more than one class which are extended by different entities : "from com.hello.AbstractEntity"