# Hibernate with multiple schemas/namespaces and one SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, multiple-databases

I have quite a large application with several hundred tables.

For organisation purposes I would like to break out the tables into groups (say 5 or so) and have them in different schemas in the database. I only want to use one database so I can still join tables together across schemas, so just one SessionFactory.

However I am not sure what would happen if we had name clashes across all the schemas. I can easily have different packages in the code for the hibernate objects, that's not a problem. But when it comes to HQL if I have two entities both called "Customer" in different packages is it possible to distinguish those in HQL queries? Maybe with some sort of prefix?

Any suggestions appreciated or any other pitfalls you see with trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this, but it should basically work.

Hibernate doesn't allow having the same class name mapped more than once (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327682/hql-with-fully-qualified-class-name)), unless you use entity names. (To be very precise: Hibernate doesn't allow the same entity name used more than once. Classes have its class name as entity name when not specified something else).

There is not much bout it in the documentation. See [chapter 5.3, Mapping a class more than once](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-entityname).

Entity names can be used in:

- queries
- when saving entities (in your case it should not be necessary to specify an entity name, because it is not the same class that is mapped more than once. But you need to try).
- when mapping references (same here: it shouldn't be necessary in your case)

Good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks, after some investigation I believe it is possible to make this work by prefixing the entity names with a "schema". So instead of "from Table" you do "from schema.Table". Setting the name property of the @Entity annotation seems to do the job.